# Losing array during variable assignment as part of a condition

Tags: php

I'm attempting to troubleshoot some code and something is happening that I can't make any sense of... I have a `$forum` object which contains a `threadExists` method, which returns an associative array of any results found or `false` otherwise.

The following will print the array as expected:

```
if (!$test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id)) {
    // do something
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($test);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

However; by adding a condition the screen will simply print `bool(true)`:

```
if (!$test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id) {
    // do something
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($test);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Why is the array lost?

I'm using PHP 5.4.12.

Comment: [The precedence of `=` is lower than that of `||` or `!=`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: `threadExists` is a bad name for a function that may return an `array` :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be found in the language manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it like this:

```
if(!$test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id)
```

1. Assign `$forum->threadExists($thread_id) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id` to `$test`
2. Negate and check the value of `$test`

And since `$forum->threadExists($thread_id) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id` evaluates to `true`, so you get `true` assigned to `$test`.

Fix is:

```
if((!$test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id))||($test['topic_id'] != $topic_id))
```

Answer (score 2):

operator precedence causes it to be interpreted like this

```
if (!($test = ($forum->threadExists($thread_id) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id))) {
    // do something
}
```

more clearly,

```
$test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id;
if (!$test) {
    // do something
}
```

you can force the correct behavior with parenthesis

```
if (!($test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id)) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id) {
    // do something
}
```

personally, I would write it like the following, because I hate code that is even slightly tricky to read

```
$test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id);
if (!$test || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis issue. You're assigning to `$test` the value of the compound condition, so it will have a boolean value based on whether either side of it resolves to true. Try:

```
if (!($test = $forum->threadExists($thread_id)) || $test['topic_id'] != $topic_id) {
```